# microcontroller to drive relay using uln 2003a

Tags: microcontroller, relay

I am getting around 2v from microcontroller port and I am using uln2003a to drive the relay.
is 2v from microcontroller is enough to switch on the relay using relay driver.
if not what should I use to amplify it.

Comment: What does the data sheet say?

Comment: data sheet tells about the maximum voltage that can be carried by uln2003a.... till now I haven't seen anything about minimum voltage

Comment: It's in the data sheet - read it properly.

Comment: Required information is in the data sheet - question should be closed.

Comment: if the required voltage is less what should I do to amplify it

Comment: Have you tried looking for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2003A is a darlington driver chip.  Driving "Voltage" isn't what switches it on or off, driving current does.  The datasheet really does specify that the minimum on current is 1.35mA maximum.  Can you deliver that?

If not.....

If you have 2V out, and one relay, just use a simple transistor to switch the relay on.
2V to the base of an NPN transistor, with a 470 or 330 ohm base resistor should work.  Put the relay coil in series with the collector, and ground the emitter.

Or, use an Opto-isolator like a 4N35 or so.  2VDC should be more than enough through a 47 or 68 ohm resistor to drive the input side.

You really haven't specified enough information for a detailed answer, so this one is general.